# How to check if Bluetooth is discoverable?

Tags: bluetooth

I know I can make Bluetooth discoverable or undiscoverable with `hciconfig hci<X> piscan` and `hciconfig hci<X> noscan`, but how can I check whether it is currently discoverable or not?

Answer (score 1):

If `hciconfig` reports `UP RUNNING PSCAN ISCAN` it is discoverable, if it only reports `UP RUNNING` it is not.